# Integrating a dynamic file browser with CKeditor

Tags: ckeditor

I have a file browser / uploader developed for my own site.

Is there anyway to have CKEditor call a function to show a file browser, instead of opening a new window with a url.

Edit:
Specifically, I want to show a div already on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Well, with ckfinder, then you can do it so.

```
CKEDITOR.replace("pagebody",
        {

        filebrowserBrowseUrl :'ckfinder/ckfinder.html',
        filebrowserImageBrowseUrl : "ckfinder/ckfinder.html?Type=Images",
        filebrowserFlashBrowseUrl : "ckfinder/ckfinder.html?Type=Flash",
        filebrowserUploadUrl : "ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php?command=QuickUpload&type=Files",
        filebrowserImageUploadUrl : "ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php?command=QuickUpload&type=Images",
        filebrowserFlashUploadUrl : "ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php?command=QuickUpload&type=Flash"

        });
```

Comment: No, that just lets you open up new windows. I edited the question to be more clear.